# How do I install gedit-2

Tags: 12.10, gedit

I want to install gEdit 2.0 on my ubuntu 12.10. The purpose is testing a plugin that seems not to have support for 3.0 or above.

My current version is:

```
vlad@computer:~$ gedit --version
gedit - Version 3.6.1
```

I tried so far looking for an older package on the internet but I didn't find anything.

Any suggestions on how to install it would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For now, the **only** supported version of `gedit` on Ubuntu 12.10 are **3.6.1** and **3.6.0**. You can check this with the command

```
apt-cache policy gedit
```

This gives an output

```
apt-cache policy gedit
gedit:
Installed: 3.6.1-0ubuntu1
Candidate: 3.6.1-0ubuntu1
Version table:
*** 3.6.1-0ubuntu1 0
    500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-updates/main i386 Packages
    100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
 3.6.0-0ubuntu1 0
    500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal/main i386 Packages
```

version 2.0 is very old one and is no longer supported on Ubuntu 12.10.

The only feasible solution for testing the plugin seems to be that you **get an older version of Ubuntu** which supports gedit 2.0, run it in VM and install and test the plugin there.